# Area code not set error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cli, magento2.4.6

I have created one custom command. That command is used when i need to generate some specific file. When i run setup:upgrade command then i give me error like "**Area code not set**".

Below is code example.

```
$this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
if ($input->getOption(self::GENERATE_NEW_MENU)) {
    $output->writeln('<info>Generating static navigation:<info>');
    $generated = $this->abcModel->generateNavigation(1);
    if ($generated) {
        $output->writeln('<info> generated successfully.<info>');
    } else {
        if ($generated->getMessage()) {
            $output->writeln('<error>Having issue while generating static navigation<error>');
            $output->writeln('<error>Exception: ' . $generated->getMessage() . '<error>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For CLI command it is good to set Global area code instead of Frontend $this->appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);

Comment: Yes if i set AREA_GLOBAL or AREA_ADMINHTML then also it gives the same error.

Comment: try to put code into the `try-catch & finally`.

Comment: In which file you write above code?

Comment: @Harishkuril already added.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i have created my custom module path like app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Console/Command/Command.php File

Comment: Share the file code into your question.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya file content code same as above added in question.

Comment: Not only this, share whole code.